# MS SQL try catch ignored when executed by php mssql_query

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, try-catch

I simplified my problem with a simple stored procedure in MS SQL 2005 with a try catch block.

It goes like that:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE testError

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @X INT
    ---- Divide by zero to generate Error
        SET @X = 1/0
        select 'Command after error in TRY block' AS retour
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        select 'Error Detected' AS retour
        return
    END CATCH
    select 'Command after TRY/CATCH blocks' AS retour
END
```

When I execute it in management studio, I get the following result: Error Detected, which is what I want.

But when I execute it in PHP 5.3.2 with mssql_query, I get the following result: Command after error in TRY block

Why my catch block is not triggered when an SQL error is encountered?

I want SQL to stop further execution and go to the catch block, as it does in management studio.

Thanks a lot for your help!

edit : added `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` because they are present in my test procedure

edit 2 : I tried with changing the division by 0 by another error since someone pointed me some config may ignore them.  I replaced it by a failed insert which returns "String or binary data would be truncated.".  The same problem still occurs.

**edit 3 : Important info :** I finally made it work with PHP with a different error.  I generate an error with `drop table #notExistingTable` and this time, it goes to the catch block and everything works fine.  But with the division by zero or with the "String or binary data would be truncated." it doesn't work.  Seems like some errors are ignored and some triggers the catch block.  Is there a specific config in PHP that I can change to act the same as management studio and catch the same error severity?

Comment: Are you actually testing on this procedure ? or is there another similar procedure ? The `RETURN` key word in your catch block would make sure that once you have entered the catch block nothing after the key word `RETURN` gets executed. Its hard to believe what you are saying.

Comment: If you're really using 2008 and called `SET ARITHIGNORE ON` this could happen.

Comment: I tried to SET ARITHABORT OFF and SET ARITHIGNORE OFF just to be sure they were not interfering. I still have the same problem.  Error handling works fine in Management studio but not when called by php.

Comment: M.Ali yes I'm only testing with this procedure.  My real procedure has a lot of other stored procedure call in it and I wanted to test the problem at his simpliest form.  I also tried to call the test procedure from command line and the try catch works well while mssql_query has the problem.  I also tried running it on a Laravel server I have, the same problem happens.

Comment: Did you solve this? Because I'm having the same exact problem.

Comment: Unfortunatly no.  Since in my case the procedure is almost bullet proof and I was not expecting any errors, and since I noticed some errors were handled (like said in my edit 3), I accepted the fact that the catch ignores some errors when run from PHP.  I would like to know more about it if someone comes with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this thread is old but I have verified this error. The offending parameter is `ARITHABORT`, the PHP script needs to run a `SET ARITHABORT ON query` before sending the `EXEC` query. You can replicate in management studio by using `SET ARITHABORT OFF`

If `ARITHABORT = OFF` for the connection, the procedure will terminate at the DIV BY 0 line and CATCH will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning of the procedure. Maybe the error is due to attempt to execute the select statement after the "exception" statement.

Comment: I tried your proposition.  In management studio this still works fine, the error is handled in the catch block and the execution don't go further in the try block.  But this still don't work when called by PHP, the execution in the try block continues.  I'm very confused with this problem.

Comment: I can't comment on the previous answer, but instead of dividing by zero you can use `raiserror ('Error', 18, 1)` to generate exception with higher severity to workaround the issue with PHP.